# Can't find 100gb of movie files on my macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, storage

I have a small problem with my ssd of my macbook. I have been deleting some files to make some space. If I go to 'apple' -> About this Mac -> Storage, I see I have 117 gb of video files on my macbook.

If I search my entire storage of my macbook, I can only find 15gb in my Movies map and 30gb in my downloads map. I seriously can't find the other files and my trashcan is empty.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Have downloaded any videos such as Podcasts from iTunes Store ? If yes, means you can find them inside the iTunes folder in Music folder.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Spotlight Search]

If you know the name of one of the movies (files) that you are looking for or if you know what format the movie is in (extension) then you should be able to use Spotlight search

My favorite way to bring it up is hit Command-Space and you will see a search bar in the middle of your screen (Yosemite)

Start typing the name or file extension and if it exists, you will start seeing search results pop up.

Select any of the files and hit **Command-I** for *Get Info* and you should see a window like this pop up:

[image: Get Info]

Under the "General" tab, you will see a field labeled "Where".  This is the path to your file where it's located.  In this example, the location is ***/Applications***.

You can now use Finder to "Go to that folder".  Hit Shift-Command-G and type that location into the dialog box.  A Finder window will open, at that location.  Your file(s) will be there.

As for names - well, you will be the one who knows what they are.  As for the extensions, there are many, but some of the most common are .MP4, MPEG, and MOV.  for a complete list, check out [Video File Extensions](http://fileinfo.com/filetypes/video)

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a 6 year old question now but in case someone else stumbles across this - you could use software like grand perspective (http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/). This will show up visually the large files on your hard drive and will allow you to instantly see where the movies (or any other large files are).